# Using the isAbsolute() function in Javascript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In a `node js` script, I am using the `path.isAbsolute` function to detect if a string is an absolute path or relative.

I was able to use it successfully as follows

```
var pathvalidator = require('path');
console.log(pathvalidator.isAbsolute('D:/a/1/s/packages/lib/components/ContextualMenu/ContextualMenuItemWrapper/index.js'))
```

and get the expected result of `true`

However, when I try the same on the browser via a React application or using the debug console, I get the result to be `false`.

I can't think of a reason why this is happening. I did verify that no leading/trailing spaces are added by adding parantheses before and after the string and verifying, in the browser case.

[image]

Comment: How are you using path api in browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it seems from question, the path library of node.js you must be using on browser side. However the implementation of path api in node.js is kept considering only os based file/dir paths. You can see the implementation here : [node.js/path](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/path.js#L349)

Or you can see below which

```
 isAbsolute(path) {
validateString(path, 'path');
const len = path.length;
if (len === 0)
  return false;

const code = path.charCodeAt(0);
return isPathSeparator(code) ||
  // Possible device root
  len > 2 &&
  isWindowsDeviceRoot(code) &&
  path.charCodeAt(1) === CHAR_COLON &&
  isPathSeparator(path.charCodeAt(2));
},
```

You can see that it search for "/" starting character or a character like "C" or "D" as first character followed by a ":" which is not going to validate the urls like :
"http://something.com/somepath"

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I feel the string mentioned in the original post which is resolved as `false` above, does pass each of the conditions above. It does start with a windows device root, it is followed by a semicolon and the  character at index 2 is a path separator.

Comment: Oh... It seems I didn't look at the question carefully. You can downvote this answer. Also I don't see any reason why it won't work in this case. Have you made sure that all other dependent libraries are also imported in browser (Or all node.js libraries)

Comment: Accepting this solution, since the implementation you linked to above, was useful in my re-implementation of the isAbsolute function. Thanks.